# Windows Presentation Forms create unique forms for new users

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a simple login application using WPF c#. I got the login part down but I cannot figure out how to create unique pages for individual users.If user "A" creates a new account, then he should have his own new profile form. This means every time I create a new user,  a new profile form is generated and that new form is assigned to the user and no other user can make modification to that user's profile. For example: Skype profile. I am sure there are questions like this floating in stackoverflow but I can't find them. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking the problem.  The *form* is the same for all the users.  The *content* of each user's form varies.  When the user logs in, your database should store some variables detailing that user.  Simply set the forms controls to reflect the users details.  Don't "create a new profile form".